# return "something"; return; - does the second parameter has a purpose?

Tags: php

In this given example;

```
public function something($input)
{
    if(something) //true case
       return "something";

    if(another something) //true case
       return "another something";
}

$this->something('something');
```

Should I use `return;` to make sure function doesn't continue running after first `TRUE` case? Like;

```
if(something) { //true case
    return "something";
    return; //stop the execution
}
```

Is it necessary, or a single return is already stop the function's execution?

Comment: A return always ends the function execution. You could always have only one return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function

— http://php.net/return

So after the first `if` statement with a true result, the function *will* end.

Your second piece of code, however, which has confusing indentation and is better written as:

```
if(something) { //true case
    return "something";
}
return; //stop the execution
```

…will return and end the function if the first case is true or false, so the second `if` statement will never be reached.

If, on the other hand you had:

```
if(something) { //true case
    return "something";
    return; //stop the execution
}
```

Then the second `return` would never be reached because the first one would end the function immediately.

Comment: Take a careful look at OP's code snippet. if condition `something` will be `false`, second `return` will be reached and will stop script execution (assuming OP is asking to ensure that function won't be executed even if condition is `false`) with returning null. I don't see it logical but this will happen.

Comment: Arghhh. Who had the stupid idea of allowing an `if` statement without braces?

Comment: Okay, this was the answer I'm looking for. I'll select this as the correct answer in few minutes. Seems like the second return; is completely unnecessary since first return automatically stops the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Once the first return has been met by PHP, the code under it won't be run.

To stop all execution (if there was an error with return), would be `exit;`

Answer (score 0):

In your last bit of code you can leave out the last `return` as it'll never get there.

In the first bit of code, you should definitely have a `return null` or `return false` at the end in case it hasn't matched any of the conditions.